# Requested URL not found with mod_wsgi in Django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get django to work on apache with mod_wsgi. My djang.wsgi code is:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('C:/djcode/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And my configuration in 'httpd' is:

```
Alias /static/ "C:/djcode/mysite/static/"
<Directory C:/djcode/mysite/static/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / C:/djcode/mysite/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory C:/djcode/mysite/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /files/ "C:/djcode/mysite/files/"
<Directory C:/djcode/mysite/files/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In the folder 'files' are files where I read data (not databases) which are used to output in templates.

The urls.py code is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^all/$', all),
    ('^(sport)/$', gen),
    ('^(teknology)/$', gen),
    ...
```

When I start Apache, `localhost`, the message is `"It works!"`. But when I try `localhost/all`' or `localhost/mysite` or `localhost/mysite/all`, the browser says `"The requested URL /all` was not found on this server`. I can not understand where does it fail

Comment: Are you sure you're not running another server on your computer? I had this problem once, and the solution is adding the port (:8000 by default) after localhost.

Comment: No, I am not running any other server. As I said //localhost, alone works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the definition or class for `all`? It's technically the controller. Can you post it?

This line routes it:

```
('^all/$', all)
```

But we don't know what `all` is.

Comment: 'all' is a function in views.py file: def all(request)... it works fine with Django server

Comment: Does it return anything? It might work fine with django server but not with Apache. Can you post the whole method?

Comment: It a very simple method, one line of code: return render(request,'all.html'). 'all.html' is a simple template(html) that just gives some explanation text about the site. Of course I have more complicated templates, but I am trying to get to work the simplest one. A think I have configuration problems, nut don't know how to fix them

Comment: [Thu Oct 31 16:52:18 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: C:/djcode/mysite/apache/django.wsgi. Maybe this is the problem, it can not find the wsgi file. Can be these combinations of slashes '/' in Windows?

Comment: That file exists write? It might need to be writeable. It says it can not find **OR unable to stat**. Give us the permissions on it (do an ls -hla in the console).

Comment: I solved the problem: I put "WSGIScriptAlias /mysite C:/djcode/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py". Thank you @virTuexru that instructed me to look at the error log file.

Comment: Glad you fixed it! I use Gunicorn with Django so I wasn't aware on how to properly setup the Apache config. Looks like you did a good job. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, you have the VirtualHost configuration correctly setup in the httpd.conf file. Try using localhost first (as the ServerName) and see if it works.